# Theory: Is flushing a file ten times per second a bad idea?

Tags: python, file, flush

I have a Python script that logs data from several sensors. The datarate for each sensor is 10Hz. I want to plot or analyze this data in approximately realtime with other programs. The brute-force way (foregoing more elegant solutions that use databases, sockets, or other fancy constructs) would be to simply flush the output file every 100ms.

I have a feeling this is considered a bad idea. But why, specifically? Will my hard-drive (spinning rust) die an early death? What if I use an SSD? Do OS-level buffers (Windows) save my hardware?

Comment: You can put your file on ramdrive if you are afraid, but I think your write-rate is probably to small to make much difference (although you didn't specify how large your data unit is). What I would be concerned about would be readers reading file that is inconsistent, since it is edited at the same time.

Comment: Yes, using a file to pretend it's a pipe is a bad idea. Why are you afraid of doing things that are elegant?

Comment: @Sneftel: Some of my analysis programs only support file I/O. Hacking around that is suboptimal, considering that this is a system that has to run for the next 10 years, self-supported by scientists without CS background. Apart from that, I am specifically interested in *why* flushing a file many times a second is a bad idea -- which I tried to convey by including the "Theory:" prefix in the title.

Comment: @MartinJ.H. Because it's not designed or guaranteed to do what you're trying to accomplish. It doesn't provide atomicity or bounded latency. Realtime I/O to file-like objects is what named pipes are *for*, and you should take some time to learn what they are. This question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).